# Remember webform textfield for next entry

Tags: webforms

I would like to know what is module to remember webform textfield or select option, so once fill in or selected, the next entry use the previous entry. In webfform autocomplete, typing several characters still required.

Is that possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use case of the [Webform Field Repeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_field_repeat) module:

> The Webform Field Repeat module enables the webform to remember
>   selected field entries from current submission for up to an hour. It
>   uses the $_SESSION to do so. If the session is active, the form will
>   be populated with selected entries from remembered submission when
>   opened again.
>
> The fields can be selected on Webform >> Form settings for each
>   individual webform. Once the fields has been selected the end users
>   will see a check box at the bottom of the form that they can check to
>   have the form populated when they open the form for a new submission.
>   This module depends on Webform module.